# Multiple ajax requests don't work on my php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the basic php webpage, I have there 3 textfields and 2 buttons.
The first textfield and button look like this:

```
    <input type="text" value="" id="city">
    <input type="button" id="visit" value="visit"/></div>
```

and right after that in my html code I have the script:

```
<script>
$( "#visit" ).click(function() {
  var text = $("#city").val();
 $.ajax({
        url: 'php.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    text: text
                },
                success: function(response) 
                {

                    $('#city').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#visit').prop('disabled', true);
                    alert("Thanks!");

                }
        });

});
</script>
```

This works fine, I get the confirmation popup and the fields are disabled. Later on I have another textfields:

```
<input id="mail" name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required>
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="gobutton" value="go"/>
```

and some time later in the code I have the ajax script:

```
<script>
$( "#gobutton" ).click(function() {
  var mail = $("#mail").val();
  var text = $("#mytextarea").val();
 $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            mail : some_mail,
            text : some_text
            },
                success: function(response) 
                {
                   alert("Thanks!");    
                }
        });

});
</script>
```

but I don't have even the alert message here... What can be the issue?

Comment: You are passing some_mail and some_text in data while your variable names are mail and text.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the second ajax request hits the server? added `error:` handlers to either to see if something blew up client-side?

Comment: you assign the values to variables, mail & text.  Later you use some_mail & some_text.  Do you know if jquery will even make the call with those undefined vars?

Comment: Thanks, Jay and you guys noticed my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mis-matched variable names -

```
$( "#gobutton" ).click(function() {
  var mail = $("#mail").val(); 
  var text = $("#mytextarea").val();
 $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            mail : mail, // note change to match actual variable
            text : text  // note change to match actual variable
            },
                success: function(response) 
                {
                   alert("Thanks!");    
                }
        });

});
```